# Get a value of one textarea from a set

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value of a specific textarea while having more than one.
Indeed I get the value of the first one but I can not get what is next.
I have tried the following but did not work.

```
// jquery:
$('.SendDescription  ').click(function() {
 var description  = $('.description ').val();  
 //var description  =  $(this).closest('label').find('.description').val(); !!! Not working ...
// var description  =  $(this).prev('.description').val();  !!! Not working ...
if (description.length < 3) {
     // do NOT process the form.
   }
// html:
1-  <textarea   class="description ></textarea> 
<input  type="button"  value=" send " class="SendDescription  "  />

2-  <textarea   class="description ></textarea> 
<input  type="button"  value=" send " class="SendDescription  "  />

3-  <textarea   class="description ></textarea> 
<input  type="button"  value=" send " class="SendDescription  "  />
  ..............
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have unwanted space in your markup in the class attribute plus unclosed quotes etc, not sure if that is copy paste issue. CHeck this http://jsfiddle.net/C92N6/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1009603/psl It is working on jsiddle b ut I get error message:

Comment: TypeError: description is undefined
if (description.length < 3) {

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the button and the textarea are siblings, you can do:

```
var description  = $(this).parent().find('.description').val();
```

Comment: `closest('*'`) is the same as `parent()`.

Comment: @SLaks - Yes! Cleaner to use parent() in this case.

Comment: Been using `closest()` for everything, and for a minute forgot about the existence of `parent()` :-)

Comment: There was an incorrect space after `.description` in the selector. Should work now.

Comment: This will ofcourse work. Maybe after you cleanup the HTML. For example, you haven't closed the quotes after description in the HTMl (or maybe its a typo in the question?)

Comment: I get this message: 
TypeError: description is undefined
if (description.length < 3) {